# How do I match table entries to a second table's list entries in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, grepl

I have two tables, table1 has a column of strings. I'd like to find the matches of each string in another table, table2, but in the corresponding table2 column, each cell contain lists per row entry.

So far, I have figured out how to use grepl to match particular entries:

```
grepl(table1$label[i],table2$labels[[j]][k])
```

for some i, j and k. i and j are fixed as they are the number of rows in table 1 and table 2 respectively, but k is some positive value, so i have something like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(table2){
    for(k ?){
    grepl(table1$label[i],table2$labels[[j]][k])
    }
  }
}
```

i'm not really sure what to put for the k loop.

what i'd like to do once I've identified the table2 rows which contain the table1 strings is to report back the corresponding values from a different table2 column and append these back to the corresponding string row in table1, so i'm guessing i'm going to need a few more for loops... are there any shortcuts for multiple referencing problems such as this?

Some example data (note there are also missing values in table2 lists, but i'm assuming when matching these just get ignored, the other entries are character class):

Table 1

```
    label 
1   Tom     
2   Gemma     
3   Graham
```

Table 2 (updated)

```
     item      labels 
1    Apple     Tom, ,John, ,Terry,     
2    Orange    Bryan, ,Graham,  
3    Pear      Finn, ,Gemma, ,Graham,
```

Output

Table 1

```
    label   item
1   Tom     Apple
2   Gemma   Pear  
3   Graham  Orange, Pear
```

---

From using `dput` I get

```
Table1 <- structure(list(label = c("Tom", "Gemma", "Graham")), .Names = "label", 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


Table2 <- structure(list(item = c("Apple", "Orange", "Pear"), labels = list(
    structure(c("Tom", "", "John", "", "Terry", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 
    1L)), structure(c("Bryan", "", "Graham", ""), .Dim = c(4L, 
    1L)), structure(c("Finn", "", "Gemma", "", "Graham", ""), .Dim = c(6L, 
    1L)))), .Names = c("item", "labels"), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Addendum: regarding my initial use of `grepl`, some of the labels in Table2 only have a partial match to the label in Table1, but the names are unique in Table1, so I'd like to apply matching the Table1 label, for example `Graham` (Table1) to both `Graham` (Table2) and `Graham Green` (Table2) e.g.

Table 2 (version2)

```
     item      labels 
1    Apple     Tom, ,John, ,Terry,     
2    Orange    Bryan, ,Graham,  
3    Pear      Finn, ,Gemma, ,Graham Green,
```

The output Table1 would be the same.

Comment: If you want working solution, please provide example data sets and desired output.

Comment: With data containing lists (like your "Table 2"), we probably need the data itself to understand how it's formatted. Consider `dput` or showing the code used to make the table.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, I've never used `dput`, very useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(Table2)[, list(label = unlist(labels)), by = item]
setkey(res, label)[Table1, toString(unique(item)), by = .EACHI]
#     label         item
# 1:    Tom        Apple
# 2:  Gemma         Pear
# 3: Graham Orange, Pear
```

What I basically did here is to split `labels` in `Table2` per each item. Then I've aggregated the unique items per each label while performing a binary left join back to `Table1`

---

**Edit** for your new `Table2` you could modify the code to

```
res <- setDT(Table2)[, list(label = unlist(labels)), by = item]
Table1["item"] <- sapply(Table1$label, function(x) toString(unique(res[grepl(x, label), item])))
Table1
#    label         item
# 1    Tom        Apple
# 2  Gemma         Pear
# 3 Graham Orange, Pear
```

Comment: Thanks David, I tried your code, but I couldn't get it to work, maybe it's the data input - i've provided the `dput` of the tables in my question to clarify.

Comment: Hi David, will the above code need to be edited if my labels in table 1 and 2 include full names like `Tom Jones` or hyphenated names like `Gemma Austen-Davenport` instead of just `Tom` for example or if there are any other special characters like `/`?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you try it?

Comment: It works for the example I've put. I'll try it again on a bigger example and see. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out my problem - I only have "Tom" in table1, but I sometimes have "Tom Jones" in table2, but I know that the first names are unique already in table 1, so I want to incorporate a partial match and not necessarily a full match

Comment: Hmmm.. That's a whole new complication to the question. In that case the code will have to be modified I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was thinking of using `pmatch` or `str_match` somewhere in between and will experiment with it - that's kinda why I started with the grepl forloop command, but I forgot to explain that!

Comment: I don't have time to go trhu this right not, but maybe you should make your question more similar to your actual data

Comment: No worries! My apologies, it was an oversight - but that explains at least why I was using grepl. Thanks again!

Comment: I figured a solution. See my edit. We can probably leave this in this thread and delete the new one if you want.

Comment: Thanks David, this code works very well, thanks - yes, I can delete the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **qdapTools** approach which uses **data.table** in the backend.  Your data type is a bit ambiguous.  `dput` would have been helpful here.

What I believe your data is based on the NA comment

```
Table1 <- read.table(text="   label 
1   Tom     
2   Gemma     
3   Graham", header=TRUE)


key <- list(
    Apple  = c('Tom', NA, 'John', NA, 'Terry'),
    Orange =  c('Bryan', 'Graham'),
    Pear =  c('Finn', 'Gemma', NA, 'Graham')
)
```

Now to lookup the values:

```
library(qdapTools)
Table1[["item"]] <- lapply(Table1[[1]], lookup, key)

##    label         item
## 1    Tom        Apple
## 2  Gemma         Pear
## 3 Graham Orange, Pear
```

If you do have a `data.frame` then try:

```
key2 <- data.frame(x = names(key))
key2[["item"]] <- key

Table1[["item2"]] <- lapply(Table1[[1]], lookup, setNames(as.list(key2[[2]]), key2[[1]]))
```

If the column is indeed a collapsed/pasted vector:

```
key2 <- data.frame(x = names(key))
key2[["item"]] <- lapply(key, paste, collapse=", ")
Table1[["item2"]] <- lapply(Table1[[1]], lookup, setNames(strsplit(as.character(key2[[2]]), "\\s*,\\s*"), key2[[1]]))
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I provided the `dput` of the tables above to clarify, I think your table1 format is ever so slightly different from mine, but I'll have a go with your code. Apologies for not providing clearer data, I will use the `dput` in the future to provide data input.